# Angularjs Post data failed using Asp.net webapi

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

i am using angularjs i want post data but its show error below picture added . When i call Get Method its successfully retrieve data from server. but post Failed

> Note: I am Using ASP.NET WebAPI

```
$http.post("http://abc/api/plumber", $scope.submitdetails).then(function successCallback(response) {
alert(response.data);

        },
          function errorCallback(response) {

alert(response.data);
            console.log('failed');

          });

}
```

webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,     OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKhtq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```